# Why is there no が in って聞いたことある

Tags: grammar

I've been using HelloTalk for a while now, and one correction I got was that 「manga series)って聞いたことがありますか？」 was wrong, and that the correct way to say it is 「(manga series)って聞いたことありますか？」

I understand basic grammar, but I've never been able to figure out why I sometimes see this grammar point written as 「たことがある」and other times written as 「たことある」. Is there some kind of nuance here, or? I understand that particles are sometimes dropped, but is there a reason behind the が not being used here?

This was the post, though for the って I accidentally wrote it as が and was corrected before I could edit it in my original post. I'm terrible when it comes to proofreading. Anyways, I have no idea about the other correction. I'm sure I made multiple other blunders in my post that weren't corrected, but here it is:

> 今日はハイキングに行く予定だったけど、1日中雨が降ったり止んだりしています。結局家で漫画を読んで1日を過ごしました。もう一度PandoraHeartsを読みました。とても面白いシリーズだと思います。PandoraHeartsのアニメも好きだけど、アニメよりも漫画の方がずっといいと思います。次回、日本語で読んでみるつもりです。
>
> 皆さん、PandoraHeartsって聞いたことがありますか？

Comment: "wrong"てこともない気がするんですが…　https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%81%9E%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%22&biw=1242&bih=568&ei=ZSmgYfjZArXFmAWIvp7YCg&ved=0ahUKEwi4oIj94bT0AhW1IqYKHQifB6s4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5&oq=%22%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%81%9E%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAkoECEEYAVCUB1i7GmChHWgBcAB4AIABogOIAacLkgEJMC41LjEuMC4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz 「って聞いたこと**が**ありますか」約 12,300,000 件 vs 「って聞いたことありますか」約 1,120,000 件

Comment: Just FYI, Hellotalk is fraught with incorrect corrections and misleading information. For example, [see this question and the comments under it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42100). If the correction you received was on a public post (as opposed to in private chat), it might be helpful to edit in a link to that post/correction, if you don't mind. (Hellotalk posts (moments) are all publicly viewable with a link)

Comment: I've added in my post from HelloTalk. Usually I can figure out if the corrections are correct or not, but when I'm really not sure, I try to get clarification from places like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131795/discussion-on-question-by--why-is-there-no--in-).

Answer (score 5):

> XXって聞いたことがありますか？

I don't think your sentence is wrong. It sounds good to me.

---

I think they made the correction probably because って sounds colloquial while たこと**が**ある does not.

> XX**って**聞いたことありますか？

↑ って and ことある (omitting が) are both colloquial.

Comment: Okay, so if I were to write it as XXと聞いたことがありますか？ Would that be correct?

Comment: @モレランド, 「XXというのを聞いたことがありますか？」 would be good.